# Vagrant and Puppet - can't find client cert and private key paths

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I'm attempting to bring up a Vagrant machine and provision it using Puppet but Vagrant is unable to find the client cert and private key paths. Here is the error I'm receiving:

puppet server provisioner:

- The specified client cert path could not be found
- The specified client private key path could not be found

Here is the relevant portion of my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision "puppet_server" do |puppet|
    puppet.puppet_server = "pg-uni-puppet-01"
    puppet.client_cert_path = "F:\vagrant-machines\Vagrant-Puppet-Agent\ssl-config\ca.pem"
    puppet.client_private_key_path = "F:\vagrant-machines\Vagrant-Puppet-Agent\ssl-config\drupal-dev-gossep-local.pem"
    puppet.puppet_node = config.vm.hostname
end
```

Do I need configuration in Vagrant to expose the location of the client cert and private key paths?

Thanks,
Pablo

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative paths to your vagrant directory.